# Are hybrid paladins able to benefit from divine sanction?

Tags: dnd-4e, paladin

The hybrid paladin entry lacks any reference to divine sanction (but then again, as printed in PHB1, so does the regular paladin).

Powers that apply the sanction to the paladin's enemies seem to be worded: "... subject to your divine sanction ..." (as compared to other effects such as "...you mark the target...") which implies that the character needs to have a divine sanction to subject.

p82 of Divine Power reads "Many new paladin powers and some of the new feats in this book subject a target to your divine sanction. Being subject to it means the target is marked by you for a duration specified in the description of the power or feat."

So can a hybrid paladin (or a multi classed paladin with power swap feats) subject a target to a normal paladin's divine sanction?

Comment: Added wording from p82 of Divine Power

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, **Divine Sanction** is usable by **Hybrid** and **Multiclassed Paladins**.  It is not a class feature of Paladins.

*Divine Power p82* has the explanation of Divine Sanction.  It notes that Divine Sanction is inherent in the feats and powers of the Paladin which reference it.  Divine Sanction is defined there in one spot so it does not need to be repeated in each power/feat.

Comment: I take it that you interpret the "your" in the first sentence from p82's Divine Sanction sidebar as indicating that anyone who can "subject" a divine sanction has a divine sanction to apply?

Comment: That is correct.